# Force.com callout: Is there a way to get the full response from the target server

Tags: salesforce, force.com

When calling a web service from Force.com, I am getting:

> System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: Unexpected
>   element. Parser was expecting element
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':HTML'

The network guys at the other end has asked to see the full response that Salesforce is getting from their server.

Is there a way to achieve that? I have tried running with debug level 'Finest' from execute anonymous, but that yields the same little message with no further detail.

Answer (score 1):

The message you are getting is because an error is generated as Saleforce is trying to parse the response is and it isn't logged unfortunately.

The parsing error is happening because instead of a SOAP message response you are getting an HTML page. This usually happens when you are accessing a service that is protected behind a firewall. Which means you may be able to see the service when browsing on your computer but remember that Salesforce is outside of your firewall and thus any communication by Salesforce to your service will be blocked.

Couple of ways to address this but this wiki topic from Salesforce best covers the options:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_security.htm

The above is specific to outbound messaging but essentially the technology issues are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am suspecting that the network admins have not opened the firewall for all of the SFDC IP ranges. Guess I'll ask them to open up for my desktop's IP so I can try out the web service with SoapUI although I am aware that it is not a guarantee that it will discover what response the web service call from Salesforce is actually getting.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that Apex includes an HttpRequest Class that works as a lower layer than the SOAP APIs.  You should be able to write up a test method that sends a hard-coded XML request to the server and dumps the HttpResponse so you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my own best answer, based on some internet research:

You can use an external tool like Runscope as a webservice proxy to automatically forward requests and pass through responses and view the XML SOAP messages. This is not a native solution on SFDC but it does do the job.

https://www.runscope.com/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Force.com is trying to parse a SOAP response that's actually just HTML. This happens sometimes when an error occurred server-side and the response is meant for a browser to display, rather than sending back an exception report via a properly formatted SOAP response.

If they can't figure out why they are not sending back a consumable SOAP response, then you can try using [other tools](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/soap_geoip_example) (outside of Force.com) to make the same webservice call from your browser and then see what the HTML actually says on return.

Comment: Will try with SoapUI (needs another firewall opening) and see what I get.